# Dart game level end

Tags: javascript

I require assistance with some logic concerning how a game of darts will end.
So far I have the following rules. A player has 3 throws per turn to whittle the score (501) down to 0. Each throw is added to an array (which holds up to three elements). Once the last dart has been thrown, the total value of all three elements is deducted from the score.

1 - if the player's score is less than zero or equal to one - bust,reset the players running total to the score at the start of the turn.

2 - player's score is equal to zero - finish the game.

3 - player must end the game on a double score (if 10 remaining, get a double 5 to finish)

This is what I have so far (pseudo code)

```
if(score < 0 or score == 1)
{
   console.log("bust")
   score = array[0];
}
else if(score == 0)
{
   console.log("game finished")
}
else if(score -(scoreNumber * 2) == 0)
{
   console.log("double out. game finished")
}
```

Fiddle added - https://jsfiddle.net/j7bzq5k7/

Comment: Why calculate a total score before the logic? surely iterating through the array on each throw and using your logic there would make more sense?

Comment: Hi; Thanks for your help - fiddle has now been added

Answer (score 0):

Score is not enough to solve this information.

When somebody throws 18, it can be single 18, double 9 or triple 6, so just knowing '18' is not enough. You have to know whether they threw doubles or trips. And if you have that information, the logic is easy.

One thing to have in mind: you don't have to throw three darts in the last turn. If you just throw one double and finish, you already have won. So you need to evaluate the win-situation after each throw.

Answer (score 0):

@tba just add a variable ' isDouble = false ' so your fiddle example can run correctly. otherwise your program checks or calculate after 3 throws only as @GolezTrol said . the game would end in several scenarios . so consider them all , i mean calculate the score after every throw (mental calculation).to check if it ends the game or not . at the third throw you can always excute your current program . that's at least what i think .